# Shadowbox.js and dailymotion videos

Tags: javascript, shadowbox, video-embedding

I have a site set up with some thumbs and links to videos hosted on vimeo. I show them in a overlay using shadowbox.js. This works perfect.

Now I want to add a video hosted on dailymotion, but it doesn't work.

The working link to vimeo video:

```
<a rel="shadowbox;height=636;width=956" href="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=11377863&server=vimeo.com&show_title=1&show_byline=1&show_portrait=1&color=00ADEF&fullscreen=1" class="player_text">thumbnail here</a>
```

The non working link to dailymotion video:

```
<a rel="shadowbox;height=636;width=956" href="http://www.dailymotion.com/swf/xd6g8y?related=0&autoplay=1" class="player_text">thumbnail here</a>
```

When the href is pasted in a browser, both links work fine. Both are played in a swf as far as I can see. So I can't see why shadowbox won't show it. Unless its a permission problem on the dailymotion video.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh! For others having similar issues... Maybe you downloaded a custom shadowbox build that dont support the format you're trying to embed :P Try getting the full verion of shadowbox.